# Thinking in Angular Way

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on project with more than 1500 HTML pages.

This project was previously implemented in jQuery and JS code. Now I have to revamp this SPA using AngularJS.

I have gone through basics of angularjs. We have several interaction on in our projects (Moving from one page to another).

1. Is `<head ngapp="routingApp">` is the right place to configure the routing for whole project or can I define it separately for each module?
2. As the project also uses jQuery for bootstrap dependency does it make any sense just to include jQuery for bootstrap?

Comment: 1500 pages with page/1 to page/1500 ? or complete different pages, layouts, contents?

Comment: Completely different pages @YOU

Comment: @YOU can you please help me sir?

Comment: start from a generator? https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly discourage you from declaring all your routing in one file. It will lead to really big file & bad maintainability.

If you have such a big project I'll advise you to read the [Google's recommendation for AngularJS structure](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub) first.

Then every developer will have a way to 'scope' his work within one module & it would be easier for him to understand it.
Moreover it would be much easier to disable/enable some modules just by excluding them from final composing&"compilation" phase.

E.g. you'll have a module that defines routes that can be reached within this module.

I strongly recommend using [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) & [Bower](http://bower.io/) (you'll have to have Node.js) to manage you dependency management as well as composition/compilation phase management.
As a teaser here you have gulp scripts compilation for fractal structure:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
var depJS = dependencies.bower.js.map(function (dep) { return config.bowerLib + dep; });
depJS = depJS.concat(dependencies.node.js.map(function (dep) { return config.nodeLib + dep; }));

var srcJS = ['app/modules/app.js', 'app/modules/**/*.module.js', 'app/modules/**/*.js'];

var libPipe = gulp.src(depJS)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(concat('lib.min.js'))
    .pipe(size({title: 'js-before lib'}))
    .pipe(gulpif(config.minimize.perform, uglify(config.minimize.js)))
    .pipe(size({title: ' js-after lib'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.scriptsOutDir));

var pipe = gulp.src(srcJS)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(concat('all.min.js'))
    .pipe(size({title: 'js-before all'}))
    .pipe(gulpif(config.minimize.perform, uglify(config.minimize.js)))
    .pipe(size({title: ' js-after all'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.scriptsOutDir));
});
```

---

The second question - AngularJS have jQLite inside it. When the jQuery is available the jQuery implementation is used. (side note: use jQuery/jqlite only in directives). It depends how vastly the jQuery library is used throughout your project & what methods are used. Can it be replaced by jqlite (limited jQuery) or can you just rewrite all jquery specific DOM/etc. manipulation by directives.
You've mentioned bootstrap - did you mean Twitter Bootstrap? If so, look at the [AngularJS UI-Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Answer (score 1):

You can definetaly separate it in modules, look at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router.

1.) If you are asking if its right to define whole routing inside 1 index.html and one angular app , yes it is right place. It is purpose of SPA

Comment: So index.html would be the right place to define all routing regardless of count of routes on project (As we have 1500 Pages)?

Comment: No index.html is right place to hold your whole SPA, but its not good idea to have routes.js and 20 000 lines of code to define 1500 pages. But in angular you can separate whole app to feature/modules and there should be defined routes for corrensponding module/feature, then you will register this module inside your app , app.module('app', ['app.dashboard']) and app.module('app.dashboard' , []).config(routes) . Then you will build whole application like a lego.